# How to run local html files on iphone and android mobiles?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-safari, iphone

How to run local files on iphone? I use Windows 7 and i have iPhone 4 and android . whenever I need to check on iphone browser I upload files on ftp and open that url in iphone.

Is there a way to check local file of my pc on iphone and android without uploading to ftp each time. Like I can see my videos of PC into iphone using **Air Server** on iphone.

I use internet on iphone and android using wi-fi router.

**I don't want to use Emulators/Simulators I'm talking about checking local files directly on devices.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access intranet pages by either typing http://local_dns_name or http://ip
As long as the iphone / ipod is on the network correctly (e.g. through standard wifi and not 3g/whatever) you should be able to access any and all local resources.

Just enter the IP address of your laptop on your iphone / ipad location bar. There is some configuration that needs to happen for this to work you can find it here:

http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-88381.html

Answer (score 1):

go to your android mobile browser and 
htttp://your local host ip/root folder

do not forget to make your local server online

Comment: How to make my local server online. my iphone and android are connected to my PC through Local wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

• First you just need to copy your html and css files to a folder in your iPhone's storage

• Next go to Chrome browser and then type :'file:///sdcard/'

• This will open your internal storage in the browser, Now you just navigate to the folder were you copied your html, css files.

• And Chrome should render you html if you've named it as index.html

• If not just select your main html file and voila!

• Chrome will render your html .