# Testing webdesign in IOS from Windows

Tags: html, ios, css, cloud

Is there a way i can test HTML files from my Windows in IOS8 (Local Files), i tried Adobe Edge Inspect but it only works with servers.
Or is there any free cloud host that allow HTML, CSS and JS files ?

**Edit:**
I'm sorry if my question wasn't detailed, i have Windows 8.1 on my computer and i want to test my html files on my Iphone (IOS8).

Comment: You want to test .html, .css, .js files? basically a website on windows (PC)?

Comment: I have windows computer and i want to test my files in my iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't elaborate your question a little bit more, I guess you have IOS8 operating system and you started Windows on a Virtual Machine.
Now if It's that true, and I assume it is, you just need to download XAMPP software, start it and add your files to your XAMPP directory.
Then just open your browser and input url `localhost:80` or `127.0.0.1`
Or any port you define.
Folder where you need to copy your webiste files is `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

**Edit 2#**
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762845/how-to-run-local-html-files-on-iphone-and-android-mobiles)

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser)

Comment: I have windows computer and i want to test my files in my iphone